# How to solve error nested mappings are not allowed in compact mappings

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, microservices, netflix-eureka

It says nested mappings are not allowed in compact mappings

```
eureka:
    client:
        register-with-eureka: false
        fetch-registry: false
        
        
server.port: 8796
  
  
spring.application.name: eurekaservice
```

After rewriting many times, it somehow stopped showing me error!
Please some one say what would be the cause?

Comment: The YAML you show is valid. We can't magically know what you did previously that yielded an error. To get an answer, edit your question to show a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that produces the error.

Comment: no ! its the same code above,  may be my spring IDE is slow to recognize , I just managed to write in application.properties file.

Answer (score 16):

check tabs and spaces. YAML expects indentations with spaces, not tabs. A lot of editors allow you to automatically convert tabs to spaces. It’s usually in the settings somewhere and you’ll want that switched on if you intend to tab-indent YAML.

Answer (score 3):

This can also happen if one or more of your values has a colon character (:), and the value(s) aren't wrapped in quotes.